# How I calculate gaps between rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Now I include some parallelism to my app `ProcessXX`, I'm not sure the data can be process in the right order. So Im working in a query to return the lower and upperbound to pass to `ProcessZZ`.

My table avl_pool has `avl_id` and `has_link` and some other fields and a steady flow of data, when new data arrive they start with `has_link=null`, when `ProcessX` finish with the rows `has_link` have the link value `xxxx` is some number.

Now on the next step I have to process only those rows with links, but I cant skip rows, because order is very important.

In this case I need `ProcessZZ(23561211, 23561219)`

```
rn | avl_id    | has_link
1  | 23561211  | xxxx     --  start
2  | 23561212  | xxxx
3  | 23561213  | xxxx
4  | 23561214  | xxxx
5  | 23561215  | xxxx
6  | 23561216  | xxxx
7  | 23561217  | xxxx
8  | 23561218  | xxxx
9  | 23561219  | xxxx     -- end
10 | 23561220  | null
11 | 23561221  | xxxx
12 | 23561222  | xxxx
13 | 23561223  | xxxx
```

Currently I have:

```
-- starting avl_id need to be send to ProcessZZ
SELECT MIN(avl_id) as min_avl_id
FROM avl_db.avl_pool
WHERE NOT has_link IS NULL

-- first avl_id still on hands of ProcessXX ( but can be null )
SELECT MIN(avl_id) as max_avl_id -- here need add a LAG
FROM avl_db.avl_pool
WHERE has_link IS NULL
  AND avl_id > (SELECT MIN(avl_id) 
                FROM avl_db.avl_pool
                WHERE NOT has_link IS NULL)

-- In case everyone has_link already the upper limit is the last one on the table.
SELECT MAX(avl_id) as max_avl_id
FROM avl_db.avl_pool
```

I can put everthing in muliple CTE and return both result, but I think this can be handle like some island, but not sure how.

So the query should looks like

```
SELECT min_avl_id, min_avl_id
FROM cte 


min_avl_id  | min_avl_id
23561211    |  23561219
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what results you are looking for?

Comment: On this case I need two columns with values `23561211, 23561219`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to assign a sequential number to each block.  This number is demarcated by the `NULL` values in `has_link`.

If this is the problem, then a cumulative sum solves the problem:

```
select p.*,
       sum(case when has_link is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by rn) as grp
from avl_db.avl_pool p;
```

This actually includes the `NULL` values in the output.  The simplest method is probably then a subquery:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             sum(case when has_link is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by rn) as grp
      from avl_db.avl_pool p
     ) p
where has_link is not null;
```

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. But Im not sure why you say include the null?. The first query seem to be ok. Because Im only interested on the first group. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNV6B.png

Comment: Nevermind I got this now. Finally I understand how the island works. Thanks.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Glad I could help.